# Javascript (string) Equality with Django Template

Tags: javascript, django

I'm new in Javascript and this is my html code that contain django template :
I have img element which src attribute is **"{% static 'basic/myImage.jpg' %}"** which actually django template to load static file

```
<img src="{% static 'basic/myImage.jpg' %}" alt="img"/>
```

then i have script (javascript) let say main.js which aim is to select that **img src attribute** which **will return literally "{% static 'basic/myImage.jpg' %}"**

```
var myImg = document.querySelector('img');
var myImgSrc = myImg.getAttribute('src'); //return a string "{% static 'basic/myImage.jpg' %}"
```

my problem is when i try equality test in web console (inspecting element) :

`myImgSrc === "{% static 'basic/myImage.jpg' %}"` is **return false**

may be there is escape character or special character to represent my django template, can someone explain how to represent django template in literal js string. Thank you sorry for my bad english.

Comment: you can't use django template language in a web console, what exactly are you trying to do with it?

Comment: What i'm trying to do is  var Foo = 'something' === 'something' (which is literal django template), django template contains {, ", ', and % but this is represented differrently in web console

Comment: Please try to make a [mcve], your question is unclear.

Comment: i have edit my question may can make my question more clear. thanks

Comment: @Sayse you're right because django is for server side scripting and js is for web interactivity. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what you are trying to do, but I'll attempt to offer some suggestions.

When the template is rendered, `{% static 'basic/myImage.jpg' %}` is also rendered, so it becomes "`/static/app/images/basic/myImage.jpg`" or whatever. So your javascript evaluation will always be false.

If you need javascript to have the actual value returned by `{% static 'basic/myImage.jpg' %}`, then you will need to include the script in the template itself, rather than a separate `main.js` file.

So, at the bottom of your `template.py` file, you could have something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    var myImg = document.querySelector('img');
    var myImgSrc = myImg.getAttribute('src');
    var Foo = "{% static 'basic/myImage.jpg' %}";
    if (myImgSrc === Foo) { // this should be true
        // do something
        }
</script>
```

Also, if `main.js` is included AFTER this script tag, it should have access to the values of `myImgSrc` and `Foo`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer i will try and figure out...., because js is for web interactivity so it has different function or string literal interpretation with django that use for server side scripting i think that is the problem i did not realize. Thanks man

Comment: You should still be able to make it work. I set JS variables with Django occasionally. Maybe the "right" way would be to set them with JSON values directly from a url. For example, a view called `get_image(request)` that returns a JSON object with the url of the image you want. Also, if my answer helped, give me some up votes :)